# Does native Kotlin Libraries work in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, kotlin, xamarin.android

I have a native kotlin library, and i will like to know if its possible to use the Andriod Binding library (Xamarin) for a native Kotlin Library. I have tried it already but when i checked the **view in object browser** it was empty. this was the steps i followed to bind the .aar file [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/). i got the dll file and added it to my app but it didnt work.

Comment: Im pretty sure it is not possible im sorry

Comment: Agree with hakim, it is not supported, xamarin android support Kotlin Standard Library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib/

Comment: Are you talking about a jar/aar-based library that was written using Kotlin? If so, yes that is supported.

Comment: Has anybody found a solution for that? Or maybe a proof that it is not supported yet.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin is a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) language, so theoretically, yes it's possible.  You'll also need Xamarin bindings for the Kotlin Standard Library as well.  Fortunately, there's a [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib/) for the Kotlin Standard Library and you'll need to include this into your project.